# MongoDB Atlas Search autocomplete index wrong scoring

Tags: mongodb, lucene, mongodb-atlas, full-text-indexing, mongodb-atlas-search

I have a MongoDB Atlas Search index with the autocomplete type on a field name and the following attributes :

```
maxGrams : 15
minGrams : 2
tokenization: edgeGram
fold diacritics: true
```

The collection contains the following names :

```
The American
The American Equity Underwriters
The American Prairie Foundation
The American Conservatory Theater
The American Club
```

With this autocomplete query :

```
{
  autocomplete: {
    query: 'The American',
    path: 'name'
  }
}
```

I'm able to retrieve all the names above with the following searchScore :

```
The American Conservatory Theater -> 15.474836349487305
The American Equity Underwriters -> 15.379003524780273
The American Prairie Foundation -> 15.379003524780273
The American Club -> 15.271049499511719
The American -> 13.68109130859375
```

Even if **The America** is the exact match it gets a lower score.

Why does the exact match searchScore is below the others ?

Comment: Can you increase `minGram` and lower `maxGram`?

Comment: Will not fix my issue and this is not scalable so far.

Comment: Well, please consider that such a large width is very expensive.

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround I found something like:

```
{
  "compound": { 
    "should": [
      {
      "phrase": {
        "query": "The American", 
        "path": "name", 
        "score": { "boost": {"value": 5}}
      }},
    {
      "autocomplete": { 
        "query": "The American",
        "path": "name"}
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

The score boost on the phrase match will handle exact match and make the exact match score higher than others.

Comment: What does your index definition look like?  Do you have a multi analyzer where name is indexed with Keyword and Autocomplete?

Comment: Yes, name is indexed with "String" and "Autocomplete" datatype.

Comment: @JonathanWadin, indexed with *both* 'string' and 'autocomplete'? My understanding is that an Atlas Search index field can only have a single 'type'? I'd love to be wrong about this, because exact match ('phrase') does not work for me on 'autocomplete' fields. Thanks!

Comment: Aha! Answered my own question: You can index a field in multiple ways like this: 

"someField": [{ /* <-- ARRAY */
    type: "autocomplete",
  }, {
    type: "string"
}]